# Can someone explain why var = input() in python doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> You want to know your grade in Computer Science, so write a program
>   that continuously takes grades between 0 and 100 to standard input
>   until you input "stop", at which point it should print your average to
>   standard output.
>
> NOTE: When reading the input, do not display a prompt for the user.
>   Use the input() function with no prompt string. Here is an example:
>
> grade = input()

```
grade = input()
count = 0
sum = 0

while grade != "stop":
    grade = input()
    sum += int(grade)
    count += 1
    print(sum / count)
```

Please dont solve it for me, but if you can point out why setting grade as "input()" doesnt work

Comment: You call `int(grade)` before you check if `grade` is the string `"stop"`.

Comment: Are you asking "Why does my automated grader not accept this?" or are you seeing a specific problem?

Comment: The title for this post is very generic. Can you make it specific to the problem you're having so that others can search for it if they have the same problem as you in the future? Also, please describe exactly what "doesn't work"--what is the expected behavior and what's your current behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input a line as the first operation and then correctly enter the loop only if it isn't "stop".

However, *that* should then be the value you use for summing rather than immediately asking the user for another value. In your current code, if the user enters "stop", there is *no* check before attempting to treat it as a number.

So, if you don't want a solution, I'd suggest you stop reading at this point :-)

---

Couldn't resist, could you? :-)

---

The solution is to simply move the second `input` call to the *bottom* of the loop, not the top. This will do the check on the last thing entered, be that before the loop starts or after the value has been checked and accumulated.

In addition, your `print` statement is *inside* the loop where it will print after every entry. It would be better

There's other things you may want to consider as well, such as:

- moving your `print` outside the loop since currently you print a line for every input value. You'll also have to catch the possibility that you may divide by zero (if the first thing entered was "stop").
- handling non-numeric input that *isn't* "stop";
- handling numeric input outside the `0..100` range.

Don't *use* this since you're trying to educate yourself (kudos on you "please don't solve it for me" comment by the way) and educators will check sites like SO for plagiarism, but a more robust solution could start with something like:

```
# Init stuff needed for calculating mean.

(count, total) = (0, 0)

#Get first grade, start processing unless stop.

grade = input()
while grade != "stop":
    # Convert to number and accumulate, invalid number (or
    # out of range one) will cause exception and not accumulate.

    try:
        current = int(grade)
        if current < 0 or current > 100:
            throw("range")

        # Only reaches here if number valid.

        total += int(grade)
        count += 1
    except:
        print(f'Invalid input: {grade}, try again')

    # Get next grade and check again at loop start.

    grade = input()

# If we entered at least one valid number, report mean.

if count > 0:
    print(total / count)
```

Comment: Or remove the one outside the loop and make a while True

Comment: @cricket_007, `while true` with a `break` is often frowned upon by educators as it indicates sloppy thinking. I don't always agree with that especially if the break conditions are complex.

Answer (score 0):

1. the first input does not work, covered by the second input;
2. when input is `"stop"`, `int("stop")` is wrong;
3. When reading the input, do not display a prompt for the user. you should print the ans after the while loop

you can use endless loop and break to solve this problem.

```py
...

while True:
    grade = input()
    if grade == 'stop':
        break
    ...

print(ans)
```